# Managing ssh private key

Tags: ssh, project, private-key

I have a project on the private bitbucket repo, and I am planning access MongoDB via ssh tunnel.

What is the best practice of storing ssh private keys?

Comment: Don't? Generate a fresh pair of keys for each user so that one user being compromised doesn't entail deploying the new key to every user.

Comment: Do you mean to generate a new pair of keys for each deployment?

Comment: Yes; each key would be generated and store locally as part of the deployment process, not associated with the source repository.

Comment: In this case, I have to associate a new public key with MongoDB instance on each deployment too. Correct?

Comment: That's correct (or rather, with the host where the MongoDB instance lives).

Comment: You are correct, with the host of the MongoDB instance. Thank you very much for the prompt response.